# Search for multiple unrelated words in Google Search

Tags: google-search

Google used to have the "+" operator, but I believe they removed it.

I want to search for Q&A sites using the following query:

> what language is * written in? + c++

However, in the top results, the term "c++" always appear right after "what language is * written in". In other words, Google is treating the entire query as one sentence. I want Google to treat it as a sentence and an unrelated word. The word "c++" can appear anywhere in the documents.

Which search operator do I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been replaced with the double quotes. Ex. `"c++"`.

[Here](http://www.googleguide.com/quote_operator.html) you can check it out.

> Google elimiated the + operator in October 2011 and expanded the capabilities of the quotation marks (” ”) operator. In addition to using this operator to search for an exact phrase, you can now add quotation marks around a single word to tell Google to match that word precisely.

So your query should be:

```
"what language is * written in?" "c++"
```