# How to force Google to use a keyword?

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search for multiple unrelated words in Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/search-for-multiple-unrelated-words-in-google-search)

I've noticed recently that Google force-feeds me certain results even if I explicitly demand that a particular keyword be included.  For example, searching for:

[image: screen shot]

None of the returned results include the word "awful", though I was under the impression that `+` forces the word to appear in the results.  Has this feature been deprecated by Google?  If not, is there a way to perform a search that **must** include certain keywords?

(P.S.  I *sincerely* apologize to fans of this comedian. I just had no examples handy that did not include him.)

Comment: @Alex, the answer is the same, but the question is quite different.  Hopefully this question will at least act as a good signpost to that one if closed.

Comment: Agreed. While the answers are the same, the *question* itself is different and will help many people who are searching for it.  Keep this question open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The plus sign no longer works in Google searches.](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/10/the-plus-sign-no-longer-works-in-google-searches/)

[Use quotes to search for an exact word.](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861)

[image: quotes]

Comment: As at 2016, the quoting method described here does not work. Instead, Google appears to have changed their "Advanced Search". Access it via:

https://www.google.com/advanced_search