# Force keyword in Google search result

Tags: google-search

I know this answer is covered already but it does not seem to be working for me. [How to force Google to use a keyword?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28034/how-to-force-google-to-use-a-keyword)

I would like to search Google and force it to return results about MotionBuilder. As you can see by the screenshot provided I have put it in double brackets like the other question has suggested. Google has ignored this however and most of the results are about Maya. Some of them are to do with motion builder but other search terms will return entirely maya results. I would like to ignore any results that do not contain the word "MotionBuilder"

[image: Google search result]

Comment: Are you sure that those results _don't_ include "motionbuilder"? Did you try negating the results you don't want, e.g., `-maya`?

Comment: That helped me find it AI E. I do find it odd though its showing so many Maya results. I viewed some of the pages and they did not contain motion builder. I think it is googles algorithm seeing that I searched for this with Maya before and it trying to show relevant results even though I am now using a completely different technology. It seems to mix up 3ds max, maya and motion builder results constantly.

Comment: It would seem those results have motionbuilder in there somewhere . . . if not Google appends something like this (missing:motionbuilder (pretend there's a strikethrough there) indicating that term was not present.

Comment: @marsh: Google indexes the web. If anyone is "mixed up", it's the people making the content. Since my hint was helpful, I'll expand it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that your results *do* contain the term you've put in quotes. It's just not displaying in the list of results. Go to the page and check. (And if you still don't see it it's entirely possible that it has been removed since the Google bot visited the page and/or people are using that keyword in their links to that content.)

If you're finding your search results are containing content you don't want, use the "negation" or "exclude" operator, which is simply a minus sign in front of the term you want to keep out of your search. For instance, if I wanted to find information about pyramids *not* built in Egypt, I might search for

```
"pyramid" -egypt -pharoah
```

In your specific case, since you want to find "MotionBuilder", but not "Maya", your search might look like:

```
"motionbuilder" -maya python scripting poly count
```

More information at [Google Search Operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?p=adv_operators&rd=1)

Comment: AI@Minus helps to not display specific content on search result with that specific pharse, but if some sites link with that anchor text, then Google can pick up that content without making bold in search result, so when you look up that content, then you can still find out that minus pharse on that content. I don't know but my answer does not deserve to be minus. Thanks

Comment: "it's entirely possible that it has been removed since the Google bot visited the page" - oh yes, the age of web-based application and otherwise dynamically generated content (especially "hot topics", "most recently published", or "random selection of related pages" lists) is still an unsolved problem for search engines :-(

Answer (score -1):

**Google checkout all the phrase (long tail keywords) in query.**

Autodesk already have content about "MotionBuilder", and many of person links to them with "MotionBuilder" anchor text, so Google also count those anchor text in their algorithm.

Now, you're all phrase did not contain to any webpage which indexed by Google, and hence Google return their best. It's all depend on your query + how people links to them with anchor text, and which type of content, they are publishing.

If you want specific result, then include all the phrase with double quota like "MotionBuilder + Keywords"